# How to add more nodes to an Elastic Search hosted with Azure

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, search, kibana, elk

I have to create new node on an Azure deployed Elastic Search and am trying to figure out how to do it in the current cluster.

My settings env look like that:

[image: Elastic Search node on Azure]

We are using the integration between Azure and Elastic.

If you know how to add a new node please share. I found how to do add new nodes if using it installed in centOS, Ubuntu and Windows. But I did not found how to do it on Azure integrated with Elastic Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hi guys! If you run in the same problem I was able to find the answer
> [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-add-more-nodes-to-an-existing-elastic-search/306818/3). So I am just copying and pasting what stephenb explained
> there.

You can reconfigure your deployment by Scaling Vertically or Adding More nodes or Both from the Elastic Cloud Console

There are a few constraints though.

1. If you are in a single zone... must scale to the maximum node size before you will get multiple nodes. In General that is 60GB of RAM.
2. If you add a zone it will add the same size node(s) to the additional zone.
3. Rule 1 Applies for multiple zones as well you need to scale vertically first and additional nodes of the 60 GB will be added.

If you go to the Deployments Edit Screen you can see this.

1 x 8GB Hot x 1 Zone
[image]

1 x 8GB x 2 Zones :
[image]

Note 2+ zone is often referred to high availability configuration and a Primary and Replica Shard will never be on the same node so it does suit that purpose, but you can also think of it as just a 2nd / additional node.. it will function just like and additional node it is just in a 2nd zone.

2 x 60GB x 2 Zones = 120GB x 2 Zones
[image]

You Can also see this in the Deployments Overview View
[image]

[Credits here.](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-add-more-nodes-to-an-existing-elastic-search/306818/4)